# Writing an email reminding a recruiter about an interview session

Tags: interviewing, email

I recently applied for a software developer profile in a start-up where the interview process consists of 3 stages - An assignment followed by an online coding round and finally a face to face discussion.

I submitted my assignment on time, got short-listed and received a Skype invitation for an interview session which is supposed to cover questions on programming aptitude. I confirmed my acceptance for the interview session and shared my Skype ID.

If I decided to remind the interviewer of our appointment on the day of the interview, how might I phrase that reminder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat not sure that's a duplicate since the OP here is asking about something prior to the interview, not how to follow up after.

Comment: Also voting to leave open: the proposed duplicate is not a true duplicate, and I do not see how this is off topic (the other reason this has been flagged)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer:** It would be a *really* bad idea to "remind" them.

What you *could* do if you really felt the need (and I would not really say is necessary) is send a message such as:

> Hi [person name],
>
> I'm just confirming my interview time at [time] and that you have my Skype ID.  Will talk to you then!
>
> Regards,
>
> Sandeep

That way it doesn't look like you're reminding them; instead it's checking that *you* have the right time rather than them :)

Comment: Thank you Jane. Actually the mail which I got was from the HR and my interviewer would be someone else(I have his e-mail id though). Maybe I should email my interviewer and add HR to CC?

Comment: No, if your contact is the HR person, then just confirm the time with them.  They can forward your "question" to the hiring manager to confirm your time.  You can omit the part about "talking to them then" :)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the mail should be addressed to the ***HR only*** and there is no need to keep the interviewer in loop? Actually, the interview session is only few hours away and I am in a dilemma whether to drop a mail or not. :)

Comment: As in my answer, I would not bother sending the email.  I think you are just getting pre-interview nerves.  If they're not there on Skype a few minutes after the agreed time, _then_ you can drop an email to your interviewer :)

Comment: Ok. That sounds a good idea. Thanks for you advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to remind the interviewer about our appointment on the day of the interview session?

**No. Assume your interviewer is a competent adult and doesn't need your help to keep his appointments.**

It would be a different matter if your paste experience with a contact lead you to believe that he would forget, but that's not the situation you're in. You already confirmed the appointment with the person who sent the invite and that's all that you reasonably need to do. As Jane said you *could* send a message to confirm the appointment with the interviewer directly if he wasn't involved in the email chain and that's a good habit when it comes to scheduling important appointments across companies, **but you'd do that directly after confirming the original invitation, not on the day of the meeting.**